# How to insert value into a column with a default value? [PostgreSQL 9.1]

Tags: postgresql, insert, default-value

I have such table:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INTEGER DEFAULT NEXTVAL('ids'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    name CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
    employer INTEGER DEFAULT (-1)
);
```

And I want to insert sth into this table (I want to leave `employer` as default, -1):

```
INSERT INTO employee (name, id) VALUES('Doe', 2);
```

but my PostgreSQL 9.1 is complaining:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "employee" violates foreign key constraint "FK_employer"
DETAIL:  Key (employer)=(-1) is not present in table "employer".
```

I know that theres no employer with id = -1 but still, I want it that way. I want to set employer as -1 for this emplyee. Is it possible with postgreSQL?

Comment: You have a foreign key defined on that column, so there is no way you can insert an id that is not present in the referenced table. If you want to signal that the employer is "unknown" set it `null`, not some "magic" value. That's exactly what `null` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the default null. Is it good?

```
employer INTEGER DEFAULT null
```

Comment: not really ... when I would like to do `select` I would like to get -1 not NULL from table :(

Comment: @Katie `select case when employer is null then -1 else employer end employer from employee`

Comment: @Katie or use the [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-conditional.html) function to automatically convert a `NULL` value to `-1`. For example, `SELECT COALESCE(employer, -1)`